# Who is Ninja Ninja?

Tags: afro-samurai

On Afro Samurai, who is Ninja Ninja?

People in the series sometimes refer to him as "Afro's imaginary friend", however, I remember times where people other than Afro could see him! (Via a scoped rifle, or binoculars).

Also, there are times where he can interact with physical objects in the real world.

So who is he? Is he really imaginary? What is the explanation for his seemingly "real" behavior?

Comment: He could also be a spirit that guids and trys to help Afro

Comment: Samuel Jackson voices both characters it's pretty much a clue it's his alter-ego .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ninja Ninja is the result of conscience and the subconscious of AFRO.
When other people saw him together with AFRO it does not necessarily mean that they actually saw **him** and it was not only AFRO (and you) have seen it.
And of course there is Justice, When he mentioned his imaginary friend they met in Chapter 5.
My best guess is that he had just supernatural powers...(let's not forget that).
Proof of this can be seen in Chapter 5, while it is cut is not bleeding to death like a normal human being, but he dissipated, and at the same time the last of the weakness of his mercy towards his old friend/anyone else

> "Alright dog, you on your own from here"

that's my opinion of course, But I think that it is uncertain for sure.

Answer (score 1):

First of all : **Ninja Ninja is the imaginary friend** of Afro.
[Wiki](http://afrosamurai.wikia.com/wiki/Ninja_Ninja) quotted:

> Ninja Ninja (ニンジャニンジャ, Ninja Ninja) is likely to be a figment of Afro's imagination to cope with severe psychiatric trauma from unbearable sights and actions of death. Being that Afro is an emotionless murderer, his mind may well have created Ninja Ninja to hold his other emotions excluding Anger and hatred ; He often hangs with Afro as his self-appointed "Road Dog". Another possible understanding of Ninja-Ninja that would also be relevant to his regular Buddhist inspired spiritual practices is that Ninja Ninja represents Afro's "Mind", which tries to affect Afro through voicing doubts and fears. Contrasting Ninja Ninja against Afro's actions in this context gives Afro a different set of characteristics. As to say, he has fears, doubts and anxieties yet continues onward in spite of them.

A canonical reference which you yourself can verify is in **Episode 5**, precisely at **14m 05s**, [Justice](http://afrosamurai.wikia.com/wiki/Justice) quotted :

> I almost chuckled when you killed that imaginary friend of yours!

Referring to the act where Afro killed Ninja Ninja but no blood splattered.

Now to add to the wiki, notice the contradictions in the two characters:

- **Afro** : Calm, composed, risk-taker, lives life on the edge
- **Ninja Ninja** : Afraid of all combats, high levels of anxiety, unconfident, slacky, always after them booties

Noticing these two character differences, it's safe to say that Ninja Ninja is the **alter ego** of the Afro's real self. He's a part of Afro that he himself refuses to acknowledge as a part of himself and treats it as somebody else. Why? Because of the [Bushido or the Samurai Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bushido). He can't allow himself (a samurai) to be unconfident, slacky, pervy or have a loose attitude. Therefore, he is tempted and warned and mocked by Ninja Ninja time and again, here and there.

Another reason I thought of, and which is mentioned in the wiki, is that all the burden of killing and slaughtering mercilessly could drive a person insane! He has to keep his mind off any such distractions. That's another reason of existence of Ninja Ninja.

Now to answer your question as to why he could interact with real world objects, he interacted with the same objects that Afro touched. Here are some instances :

1. In Resurrection he commented how awful the steak was! At the same time Afro was having the steak, but he (being a samurai after all) shouldn't be complaining about such things, but his alter ego did it for him to keep Afro calm!
2. He killed or discarded his alter ego in Resurrection by dodging a poisoned needle in such a way it hit Ninja Ninja, and also in the first season he killed it when he was about to face formidable enemies to prevent any second thoughts or distractions! And I don't remember if he was ever noticed by any other character in the anime. (Tell me on which episode at what time if I'm mistaken.)

Hope this seems reasonable!